# Get Push Notification enabled/disabled event from settings app ios?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have configured push notifications and everything is running fine, my question is how can the app know when a user has disabled or enabled push notification in real time.

Scenario: (user has PN turned off)
// in my app
1. user logs in to the app
2. he sees that PN is turned off and on tap is taken to the settings app.

// in settings app
3. user enables PN from there

-> now at this point I would like to know in my app that PN status has changed.

Please, any help or suggestion would be appreciated!!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poll for changes with this call.  You can call this on your viewDidAppear when you return to your app.  You can also call it from your appDelegate on your applicationDidBecomeActive to check someone's status.

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Can you also tell me how I can get the device token for the registered PN in the same case?

Comment: This page show's how: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns